# Filter nested NSSet with Predicates

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have a coredata model which has one to many relationship and my objetive is to filter the parent array based on a child element  (Account<->>Contact).

```
Account{

 @NSManaged public var recent_contact_id: String?

 @NSManaged public var contacts: NSSet? //Many contact in one account

}

Contact {

  NSManaged public var contact_id: String?

  NSManaged public var name: String?
}
```

At the time of saving Contacts to coredata, I keep a reference in the Account with the last updated contact_id as recent_contact_id. Finally after fetching I have an array of Accounts, and my objective is to filter the accounts based on the contact_id parameter thats been passed from the account level as recent_contact_id. partially done code as bellow.

```
   // Im stuck passing the recent_contact_id to the predicate, if i hardcode the value it'll give me the right result. but i want to pass something like $0.recent_contact_id

    let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(contacts, $x, $x.contact_id == %@).@count > 0", ??) //how tp pass recent_contact_id ??
    let filteredArray = accountsArray.filter { namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0) };
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to treat Core Data as a relational database.  Don't do that.  You don't need to store ids.  Just make a to-one relation field to the relevant contact.  Then you can simply perform a fetch against the `Accounts` specifying a predicate of `"recentContact = %@"` and passing the relevant `Contact` instance (Don't use _ in Swift either, use camelCase).

Comment: thats not the use case im trying to achieve here, this was just hypothetical scenario of the original

Comment: Then please explain what you are trying to do, otherwise it is hard to answer your question. In core data you should not be storing identifiers of other objects. You should have a relationship to the other object